# Jekyll site on gh-pages does not appear on google search results

Tags: seo, jekyll, github-pages

Jekyll website at 'https://hr-kucuk.github.io/vergilius/' does not appear on google search results. There is simple content with a few posts and I am sure the site is running properly on all aspects.

I also added sitemap.xml, by simply adding these lines of code to _config.yml:

```
gems:
    - jekyll-sitemap
```

You can check this repository at: https://github.com/hr-kucuk/vergilius

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156336?hl=en Your site is just too recent

Answer (score 0):

Probably posting a link to your site on SO will help in getting Google to index your site faster.

Also ask your friends to post a link to your site on their blogs, Twitter, etc.

Google had *"Webmaster Tools"* (renamed to *"Search Console"*) that lets you submit an URL, telling Google to reindex the URL.

Comment: Thanks you insmodscum, I am now searching about these webmaster tools of google, as wasthishelpful mentioned above in the comments. That seems to be a solution to the problem. Thanks again!